# How to use Document Provider Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, document-provider, uidocumentpickervc

I was learning a little more about ios extensions, such as:

- Today Extension
- Photo editing Extension
- Action Extension
- Custom keyboard Extension

In all of them I did not have difficulties in learning, but recently I try to learn the "document provider extension", and to my surprise not found any relevant tutorial on the Internet talking about how to use it (step by step as the others).

The only alternative I found was use the documentation, and I learned that he can access shared documents from other applications, and you can also share your own existing documents within your app.

The only tutorial I found on the net was the site [MacStories](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/implementing-ios-8-document-pickers/) but he use iCloud, and in this time I not want to use iCloud, I want do to like documentation says:

> allows other apps to access the documents managed by your app (Without iCloud)

In my case I already know how the "provider document extension" works, and so managed to create a new target type "document provider extention" and only that. Anyone know how this extension work?

Comment: Did you found some relevant tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_document_picker/

or watch the following session from WWDC

WWDC 2014 session 234

Also one of the best could be ios8 by tutorials book on raywanderlich.com but this one is not free

Comment: Thanks.. Can you please provide other references if any??

Comment: The Xamrin code is neither in Objc nor in Swift. Difficult to understand

Answer (score 2):

I am also looking for the same. There are not very much good tutorials on this topic. I'll share Some of the links that i have found.

1. https://github.com/D2B-Solution/DocumentPickerSample
2. https://github.com/ikuya/DocumentProviderSample
3. https://github.com/pavanSaberjack/PIDocumentProvider
4. https://github.com/imayaselvan/DocumentProviderExtension