# Attach documents in app, open document folder or list on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, file-upload, server

i am working on an app based on job portal, now i am stuck with document upload, i need to look for documents on device on button click, and attach document on selection.I have to upload selected document to server. how can i do this ? any way out ?

Comment: use https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html

Comment: @Vinodh how can i use it on button click ? :/

Comment: @Vinodh is it for phone documents ?

Comment: Yes please use following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/33733557/1142743

Comment: @Vinodh Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my query.Below is the code.

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {

UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu =
[[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                                                     inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

importMenu.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
[importMenu addOptionWithTitle:@"Photos" image:nil order:UIDocumentMenuOrderFirst handler:^{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];

}
-(void)documentMenu:(UIDocumentMenuViewController *)documentMenu didPickDocumentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)documentPicker

{
documentPicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```